Solution of the classical 2D quartic oscillator
Consider a classical oscillator in two spatial dimensions with Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\vec{p}^2 + \frac{1}{2}\omega r^2 + ar^4.$$
This system has two conserved quantities, the energy and angular momentum $$L=r^{2}\dot{\theta}.$$ Using polar coordinates and setting the energy to the constant $E$, we then have
$$E =\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2+\frac{L^2}{2r^2}+\frac{1}{2}\omega r^2 + ar^4.$$
The radial coordinate can then be obtained by integration:
$$t = \int_{r(0)}^{r(t)}\frac{dr}{\sqrt{2E-\frac{L^2}{r^2}-\omega r^2 - 2ar^4}}.$$
My question is, can this integral be solved analytically in a simple way? I know how to work out the orbits for the cases $L=0$ or $a=0$, but dealing with the quartic and centrifugal terms together is not something I've dealt with.
Also, I should say that actually evaluating the integral isn't too important. If that's hard to do directly, I would be happy doing something like getting $r(\theta)$ and proceeding in some less direct manner.

typically integrals involving  squar-roots of quartic expressions can be evaluated in closed form in terms of elliptic functions.

Right, as I said I know how to do that in other cases where the potential is symmetric, since you can then parameterize in terms of an amplitude and phase as $r=r_0\sin\phi$. But this potential is more complicated, so I'm not sure what variable transformation could bring us to the form of an elliptic integral.

You are right. I did not notice the $L^2/r^2$

@mikestone you did not have to notice it,  you are almost right: let $t=r^2$ and then your integrand is $\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2Et-L^2-\omega t^2-2at^3}}$, which is a cubic and thus also an elliptic integral related directly to the $\wp$ function after transforming "away" the $t^2$ term.

@hyportnex thanks for the comment, my experience with elliptic functions is limited so this has helped me figure out where to look. Could you say something more about getting rid of the $t^2$ term? My usual bag of tricks is better suited to killing the term proportional to $t$

in any polynomial $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ if you shift the variable as $x=y+b$ where $a_0b+a_1=0$ the term $y^{n-1}$ will be removed. If you do this to your integrand you get the standard form for the $\wp$ function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function
